# Lenovo unstable and sudden power-downs on battery

Tags: 18.04, shutdown, laptop, lenovo

On my Lenovo ideapad 100 which is about 2 years old, I'm running Ubuntu 18.04. Everything is fine except that last week the system starts to power-off suddenly or to display a corrupted screen for about 30 seconds and then to power off.

My work-around for now is to keep the laptop connected and 100% charged as those problems only occur when it is running on battery. I supervised the CPU temperature but I didn't remarked anything suspicious. I also booted the device without opening any applications so that CPU activity is the as low as it can be (with Ubuntu booted) but the power-off occurs nevertheless.

I'm surprised because until last week the battery kept up to 4hours, so that I eliminated all tests related to a battery problem.

Any hints would be deeply appreciated!

Output of lspci

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series SoC Transaction Register (rev 21)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 21)
00:0b.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series Power Management Controller (rev 21)
00:12.0 SD Host controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series SD Controller (rev 21)
00:13.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series SATA Controller (rev 21)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series USB xHCI Controller (rev 21)
00:1a.0 Encryption controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series Trusted Execution Engine (rev 21)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series High Definition Audio Controller (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series PCI Express Port #1 (rev 21)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series PCI Express Port #3 (rev 21)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series PCU (rev 21)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx SMBus Controller (rev 21)
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 3160 (rev 93)
```

[image: Example of the screen when disconnected from power]

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't rule out the battery if the problem only occurs when on battery. For troubleshooting, you could try an older kernel or maybe a live system. How long does the system run until it powers off?

Comment: Sometimes it happens straight after removing the power supply, sometimes it keeps for two minutes... I already tried an older kernel, but I will try the live system, too.